# NoReverseMatch at /rosetta/. Reverse for 'rosetta-file-list' not found

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I want to add rosetta to my project and use it.

First I installed it using pip -> 'pip install django-rosetta'

Then I added it to my INSTALLED_APPS

After that, I added the rosetta url to my project urls:

```
url(r'^rosetta/', include(('rosetta.urls', 'rosetta'), namespace='rosetta')),
```

But when I run the project and go to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/rosetta/", it send me back this error:

> NoReverseMatch at /rosetta/
>
> Reverse for 'rosetta-file-list' not found. 'rosetta-file-list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I have no idea where the problem is. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should set a function in view for this url

Comment: @Negar37 yes the error says that, But how I add a function to a package prepared for us? It should already has it.

Comment: The error says that the code is trying to reverse the url named 'rosetta-file-list'. So this means /rosetta/ works and a view is being called, but probably inside that view or inside the template there's a 'rosetta-file-list' url being called. This is due to the namespace you added ('rosetta:rosetta-file-list' exists), you should remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that the code is trying to reverse the url named 'rosetta-file-list'. It doesn't say that the url /rosetta/ doesn't work (it says the error is **at** /rosetta/) So this means /rosetta/ works and a view is being called, but inside that view or inside the template there's a 'rosetta-file-list' url name being resolved.

The problem is due to the namespace you added (it's now 'rosetta:rosetta-file-list' instead of 'rosetta-file-list'), you should remove it. As the [docs](https://django-rosetta.readthedocs.io/installation.html#install-rosetta) say, you should include the urls like this: `url(r'^rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls'))`.

All the urls start with *rosetta-* to avoid clashes with your own or other apps urls. Namespacing isn't necessary and actually breaks the package.